Filtering within same row
I am new to spreadsheets. I am in over my head but eager to learn!
I have created a google form to track a service technician's daily time record. The technician might visit multiple sites in a day. As Forms does not allow looping questions, I have had to create a number of duplicate sections. The Google Sheet attached to the form is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ur7eeJnEXZRNy9oWrSLpC_uD7d_c9p94gCNkuXVf2Oo/edit?resourcekey#gid=185521600
I have a couple of questions:

Is it possible to filter within a single row to extract data?


I would like to be able to SUM the "Durations" of different time "Types". For example, "Office Time" column (BN) would be SUM of "Duration" columns if the Corresponding "Type" = "Office", "Site Time" column (BO) = SUM of "Duration" columns if the Corresponding "Type" = "Service" or "File Job" etc.


I am trying to calculate the "Travel" as the difference between "Finish" of one Entry and "Start" of the next.


I figured I could just SUM (Start2-Finish1), (Start3-Finish2)...etc which works great if all the entries are filled. (BP3 should = 2.25 but comes up as -13.75 as there is no value in BG3)
Is it possible to write a formula to do this until the entries that have values and stop when the entries stop or would this have to be done with a script?


Unpivot the data, then use query(), like this:
=let( 
  unpivot_, lambda(data, numFixedCols, numColsPerGroup, let(k,n(numFixedCols),d,if(k,data,hstack(sequence(rows(data)),data)),f,if(k,k,1),g,numColsPerGroup,s,lambda(r,c,h,w,chooserows(choosecols(d,sequence(1,w,c)),sequence(h,1,r))),h,hstack(s(1,1,1,f),"Label",s(1,f+1,1,g)),i,sequence(1,(columns(d)-f)/g,f+1,g),a,reduce(h,sequence(rows(d)-1,1,2),lambda(a,r,let(x,s(r,1,1,f),b,reduce(tocol(æ,2),i,lambda(y,c,let(z,s(r,c,1,g),if(""=+z,y,vstack(y,hstack(x,s(1,c,1,1),z)))))),vstack(a,b)))),if(k,a,choosecols(a,sequence(1,columns(a)-1,2))))), 

  data, hstack('Form Responses 1'!A1:D, 'Form Responses 1'!BD1:BD, arrayformula(if('Form Responses 1'!D1:D = "Sick", iferror('Form Responses 1'!E1:BC / 0, "Sick"), 'Form Responses 1'!E1:BC))), 
 
  unpivot_(data, 5, 5) 
)

=query( 
  Data!A1:K, 
  "select Col3, Col4, sum(Col10) - sum(Col9) 
   where Col3 is not null 
   group by Col3, Col4 
   label sum(Col10) - sum(Col9) 'Duration' 
   format sum(Col10) - sum(Col9) '[h]:mm' ", 
  1 
)

See your sample spreadsheet.
